# Can a snowflake task trigger a python script?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to perform series of action after the data load is completed from snowpipe to the landing area and want to make it run on its own. Please suggest if you see any other option here if not tasks.

Comment: Tasks cannot call python scripts, but they can call stored procedures. If you provide some examples of the actions to be performed maybe it would be easier to understand your requirements.

Comment: You can find of example of it here:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Schedule-Dynamic-Stored-Procedure-using-TASK

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not directly. You may want to look at external functions.

Snowflake supports  [external functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html#platforms-that-support-calling-an-external-function) which can call a cloud api and therefore run any code that you are able to expose via a supported API.

The hyperlinked [article](https://interworks.com/blog/2020/08/14/zero-to-snowflake-setting-up-snowflake-external-functions-with-aws-lambda/) gives a walk-through of creating an external function that you can adapt to suit your needs:

This walk-through is specific to AWS, but there are options for Azure and GCP

**Platforms that Support Calling an External Function**
In general, an external function can be called from a Snowflake account on any cloud platform that Snowflake supports:

- Amazon Web Services (AWS)
- Microsoft Azure
- Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

The steps you have to take to ensure appropriate security won't fit here:
however in summary you do the following:

1. Create an AWS IAM service role to execute all of the Lambda
   functions
2. Create AWS Lambda functions for our examples
3. Create an AWS
   API gateway to expose the Lambda functions to Snowflake
4. Create an
   AWS IAM role to access the API gateway and configure it to access
   both the API gateway and a Snowflake API integration object
5. Create
   and test some external function objects in Snowflake

**Sample Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE external function external_functions.lambda.sum(filename varchar, rowcount number)
  returns variant
  api_integration = aws_lambda
  as '<https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/snowflake-external-function-stage/snowflake-sum>'
```

If you decide to leverage external functions:

You may create a task, which runs a stored procedure.

This stored procedure could for read from your load history:

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
(
select * from table(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'abc.mytable', start_time=> dateadd(hours, -1, current_timestamp())))
) q 
WHERE q.PIPE_NAME ilike 'mypipe'
;
```

And use the output from the copy history to call your external function.

This [external function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html) could trigger any action that you can program on your cloud provider. This would be a "serverless" option.

If you are running on-premise / on a cloud vm. You can write a python script that runs in airflow / cron, that processes your copy history and run the next set of actions.

[image: Sample Output from Copy History]